# Renaming multiples files with a bash loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, batch-rename

I need to rename 45 files, and I don't want to do it one by one. These are the file names:

```
chr10.fasta         chr13_random.fasta  chr17.fasta         chr1.fasta          chr22_random.fasta  chr4_random.fasta  chr7_random.fasta  chrX.fasta
chr10_random.fasta  chr14.fasta         chr17_random.fasta  chr1_random.fasta   chr2.fasta          chr5.fasta         chr8.fasta         chrX_random.fasta
chr11.fasta         chr15.fasta         chr18.fasta         chr20.fasta         chr2_random.fasta   chr5_random.fasta  chr8_random.fasta  chrY.fasta
chr11_random.fasta  chr15_random.fasta  chr18_random.fasta  chr21.fasta         chr3.fasta          chr6.fasta         chr9.fasta         
chr12.fasta         chr16.fasta         chr19.fasta         chr21_random.fasta  chr3_random.fasta   chr6_random.fasta  chr9_random.fasta
chr13.fasta         chr16_random.fasta  chr19_random.fasta  chr22.fasta         chr4.fasta          chr7.fasta         chrM.fasta
```

I need to change the extension ".fasta" to ".fa". I'm trying to write a bash script to do it:

```
for i in $(ls chr*)

do

NEWNAME = `echo $i | sed 's/sta//g'`

mv $i $NEWNAME

done
```

But it doesn't work. Can you tell me why, or give another quick solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Several mistakes here:

- `NEWNAME =` should be without space. Here bash is looking for a command named `NEWNAME` and that fails.
- you parse the output of ls. this is bad if you had files with spaces. Bash can build itself a list of files with the glob operator `*`.
- You don't escape `"$i"` and `"$NEWNAME"`. If any of them contains a space it makes two arguments for mv.
- If a file name begins with a dash `mv` will believe it is a switch. Use `--` to stop argument processing.

Try:

```
for i in chr*
do
  mv -- "$i" "${i/%.fasta/.fa}"
done
```

or

```
for i in chr*
do
  NEWNAME="${i/%.fasta/.fa}"
  mv -- "$i" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

The `"%{var/%pat/replacement}`" looks for `pat` *only at the end* of the variable and replaces it with `replacement`.

Comment: I shouldn't have removed my comment, but I saw you had answered above. Thanks.

Comment: nice, using `/%` and `--` for `mv`. I would probably include the extension in the `for` loop, `for i in chr*.fasta`

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer!

Comment: Nice use of bash substitution. +1

Comment: @Chris Dodd: taking good habits is though so useful afterwards.

Comment: One man's virtue is another man's vice -- Encouraging the use of spaces in filenames (or files that begin with `-`) is not a good thing.

Comment: Why is it not a good thing? Because programmers don't always correctly handle them? Ask the end users of computer workstations to remove all spaces, dashes, and non-alphanumeric characters from their filenames and spot their reaction :) As programmers it is our job to adapt to the possibilities of the systems we work on. As for files that begin with `-` why couldn't I name a file starting with a negative number for instance?

Comment: Very handy, I used it in cygwin on my PC, but I had an issue that SublimeText was saving it as a Windows text file \r\n, then I ran the dos2unix.exe on it and it ran just fine!

Comment: Tried to edit my last comment, but ran out of time.   Created this Gist of the file  --   [link https://gist.github.com/craiglondon/15107556eec481c57b59](https://gist.github.com/craiglondon/15107556eec481c57b59)

Comment: What does `mv --` do? I've found it [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132235/quickest-way-to-rename-files-without-retyping-directory-path) but can't figure out what it does.

Comment: @Josh `--` signifies end of option parsing. Therefore, if you have a file named `-i` for example, `mv -- -i …` will work because `-i` will not be interpreted as a switch.

Answer (score 14):

```
for f in chr*.fasta; do mv "$f" "${f/%.fasta/.fa}"; done
```

Comment: althought this would work with the given data, what about spaces in files, or files that contain `.fasta` in their filename and not only as their extension ? many things can go wrong here

Comment: fixed use of `/%` before I even got to post the above comment ;)

Comment: Ok, I added the quotes even though they almost certainly aren't needed, given the OP's example.  There also aren't likely any spurious periods in the names.

Comment: @Chris Dodd: so, now your answer is very similar to mine :) And always quoting is taking good habits. I used to use them lazily and one day came the disaster.

Comment: Removed downvote since files with spaces issue is fixed. Always use best practices when teaching others!

Answer (score 7):

If you have the [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command, you can do:

```
rename .fasta .fa chr*.fasta
```