# why this bash script is not working when trying to rename existing files

Tags: bash, batch-rename

i have this script and a dir file with some Sip_* files and i need to rename them to SIP_*

```
for i in Sip_R*.csv
do
   echo "processing $i"
   NEWNAME="$(i/Sip%/SIP)"
   echo "newname is $NEWNAME"
   mv -- "$i" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

and i receiving

```
 processing Sip_Reg-generated1415879496958.csv
 digest-reg-files.sh: line 5: i/Sip%/SIP: No such file or directory
 newname is
 mv: cannot move `Sip_Reg-generated1415879496958.csv' to `': No such file or directory
 processing Sip_Reg-generated1415879504694.csv
 digest-reg-files.sh: line 5: i/Sip%/SIP: No such file or directory
 newname is
 mv: cannot move `Sip_Reg-generated1415879504694.csv' to `': No such file or directory
```

I have modified the solution provided by [Renaming multiples files with a bash loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899135/renaming-multiples-files-with-a-bash-loop) and it is not working.

The machine is some centos, 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 and bash version is 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Have you tried using rename instead? $ rename Sip_ SIP_ *.csv
http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Comment: `NEWNAME=${i/Sip/SIP}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brackets are wacky.  The syntax for string substitution in Bash uses curly braces, not round parentheses.

Also, like [the answer you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899165/874188) explains, the percent sign anchors the substitution to the end of the string, which is not what you want here.  Use `/#` instead to anchor to the beginning of the string; or you could use `${i/Sip/SIP}` to not anchor at all (you already know the first occurrence is at the beginning of the string anyway).

```
NEWNAME="${i/#Sip/SIP}"
```

Kudos for properly quoting everything!

Comment: The percent sign in the linked answer is the suffix-anchor modifier to `${var/}`: `"${i/%.fasta/.fa}"` means that `.fasta` is only replaced by `.fa` if it occurs at the end of the parameter value. As a `sed`-like substitution, it would look like `s/\.fasta$/.fa/`. The OP might have mistaken it for `*` to match any preceding characters; its use here would seem to attempt to match everything following "Sip".

Comment: And you noted the same thing in your answer while I was commenting :)

Comment: Actually I learned something new today, I had not stumbled across this particular twist in the syntax before.  Thanks @Benoit wherever you are (-:

Answer (score 1):

The original solution mentioned above uses something like (in your case):

```
NEWNAME="$( echo "$i" | sed -e 's/Sip/SIP/' )"
```

The content of $(…) is executed in a subshell and must be regular code which `i/Sip%/SIP` is not.  Maybe a typo?